# Did ASP.NET MVC 4 default directory hierarchy change since MVC 3?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am learning ASP .NET I follow tutorial on MS site: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

I have MVC4 not MVC3 and the problem is in the beginning. In the left is how by default solution should look like an on the right how it looks on VS2013 and MVC4. Do I have to add Content and Scripts directories manually?

On MS site it says: “convention over configuration”. So if I call thoes directories Content, Scripts VS 2013 will know what is inside?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't matter if you call your content directory `Content`. You still need to provide the path to load files (e.g. `~/MyContent/img.jpg`).

Comment: Something is wrong MVC4 has content and scripts folders in a default empty project. Template includes them

Comment: if it bothers you, just `PM> Install-Package bootstrap` and they'll be back. (Though i believe you're right, the "empty" MVC project exempts them)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you add content, scripts directory, vs2013 will know what is inside.
And if you create MVC empty application, you need to manually add the required folder. So most of the people will not prefer empty application.

Else use package manager console..it will automatically install required templates, if you did not install mvc properlly. To do that, Go to Tools->Library Package manager->Package manager console.